# Modeling curved/round bulge on a flat surface?

Tags: modeling

I'm trying to model a curved bump on a flat surface like the image below:

[image]

Is there a recommended way to model this kind of shape? Should I add subdivisions to mark the outline of the bump and then have the subdivision modifier somehow create the round shape? I tried doing that but the curve I get is not defined well enough, and ends up looking like the plane has a "swollen" part instead of a well-defined bump like the one in the image...

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about using curves?

1. create a profile shape using Bezier or path
   [image]
2. create your case contour shape and use the profile curve as taper object:
   [image]

Comment: Oh, looks like a good approach! how do I make sure it merges seamlessly into the plane "underneath"? Just place it on top? Won't it cause some rendering or bleeding issues later on?

Comment: When you "extrude" the curve with the taper object and use the 2D mode, it will create an airtight mesh wherever your profile curve is place. I think what's relevant is how you draw the control points of the profile curve, not its final position when extruding the contour one.

Comment: Ok, I will try and make it work. Thanks a lot for the help!